# Website font color and size change using CSS for top nav

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

I have backend dev background but newbie to CSS. Recently launched www.feisworld.com using an existing Wordpress template. Unfortunately I notice "HOME" in top nav, upper lefthand corner is not noticeable. I want to up the size to about 24px.

Then I notice after clicking on an article the HOME button is now in deep purple, even less readable! I tried to manipulate .navigation-main .a but the entire top nav changes - including About and Podcast.

I also played with .navigation-main .current-menu-item.home-link > a, .navigation-main .current-page-item.home-link > a, with no luck.

Can someone please advice what I'm missing here and why HOME behaves differently depending on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the link of your website?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `!important` tag.

```
.home-link { font-size: 24px !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change it using :

```
#menu-item-4 > a {
    font-size: what-you-want;
}
#menu-item 4 > a:visited { /*For the link color after you click it */
    color : what-you-want;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to edit and achieve the desired result with a few more elements.

Comment: Nice ! ;) If you are satisfied with this answer please accept this one as the answer (mark it on the left)